# Windows cascade or tile for more JFrame

Tags: java

I am fairly new on Java. I have a java project which open more JFrame in which JInternalFrame  is added in different windows. I need to arrange all frame as tile or cascade as Adobe Reader does (please see the images).. I cannot use JDesktoppane to group all JinternalFrame on the same windows because the user requirment.  I have search but I didn't found a clue. It might be my poor English. Would some one give me a clue to do it. Thanks. in advance

There is my code:

```
package MyPackage;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import PDFAnnotationPackage.WindowMenu.ChildMenuItem;
import com.qoppa.pdf.IEmbeddedFile;
import com.qoppa.pdf.annotations.IAnnotSelectionListener;
import java.io.File;



public class Question extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public final static  String PDFEXTENSION= "pdf";
private ArrayList<File> fileList=new  ArrayList<File>();
private QuestionJInternalFrame  internalFrame=null;
private ArrayList<QuestionJInternalFrame>  lstInternalFrame=new ArrayList<QuestionJInternalFrame>();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (args.length>0){
        Utility.DisplayTestMsg(args[0]);

    }

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {               
            new Question();              
        }
    });

}

public Question(File  newFile) {

    String extension=getExtension(newFile);
     if ( PDFEXTENSION.equalsIgnoreCase(extension)){
          AddJPDFNote(newFile);
     }   else{
                     Utility.DisplayWarningMsg("Only PDF File");
           }


    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public  Question(){
    super("Question");

            //it is equal to this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {                      
                }
            });


           this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 500));        
           this.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
           this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);            
           this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


            // Name the JMenu & Add Items
            JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
            menu.add(makeMenuItem("Open"));
            menu.add(makeMenuItem("Save"));
            menu.add(makeMenuItem("Save As"));
            menu.add(makeMenuItem("Close"));
            menu.add(makeMenuItem("Print"));
            menu.add(makeMenuItem("Quit"));

             JMenu windowsMenu=new JMenu("Windows");
            windowsMenu.add(makeMenuItem("Tile"));
            windowsMenu.add(makeMenuItem("Cascade"));
            // Add JMenu bar
            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            menuBar.add(menu);       
            menuBar.add(windowsMenu);               
            setJMenuBar(menuBar);   
            setVisible(true);          

}
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // Menu item actions
        String command = e.getActionCommand().trim();  

        if (command.length()>1){
            menuAction(command);
        } 


    }
  private String getExtension(File file){
       return      file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1, file.getName().length());
   }

private JMenuItem makeMenuItem(String name) {
    JMenuItem m = new JMenuItem(name);
    m.addActionListener(this);
    return m;
}

private void menuAction(String command){

        boolean blnGo=false;

             if (command.equals("Quit")) {

             } else if (command.equals("Open")) {
                 // Open menu item action           
                 OpenPDFFile();

             }  else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Save")) {


             } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Save As")) {


             }else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Close")){

                 }

             else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("Print")) {
             }

    }      



private void AddJPDFNote(File file){                
    try{                             

         internalFrame = new QuestionJInternalFrame(file, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
         fileList.add(file);
         lstInternalFrame.add(internalFrame);               
         internalFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 100);       
         this.add(internalFrame,BorderLayout.CENTER);
         internalFrame.setVisible(true);

      try {

           internalFrame.setSelected(true);
       }
       catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {              
           Utility.DisplayExcecptionStrackTrack(e,"MainForm - AddJPDFNote line 401");

       }

       catch(Exception  err){
           Utility.DisplayExcecptionStrackTrack(err,"MainForm - AddJPDFNote line 406");
       }



    }
    catch(Exception  err){
        Utility.DisplayExcecptionStrackTrack(err,"MainForm - AddJPDFNote");


    }
}



private void  OpenPDFFile(){
      JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();  
    FileNameExtensionFilter  pdfType=new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF File (."+ PDFEXTENSION + ")", PDFEXTENSION);
    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(pdfType);
    fileChooser.setFileFilter(pdfType);
  //clear "All files" from dropdown filter box
    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(Question.this);
    if (returnVal ==  fileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();           
        String extension =getExtension(file);

        if ( PDFEXTENSION.equalsIgnoreCase(extension)){
          if (fileList.size()==0){

                      AddJPDFNote(file);
                  }
                  else{
                      Question a=new Question(file);
                      a.pack();
                      a.setVisible(true);
                  }
            } else{
             Utility.DisplayWarningMsg("Only PDF File");
            }

    } else if (returnVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION ) {
    // Do something else

    } 
  } 




}
```

There is another class extends JInternalFrame :

```
package MyPackage;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener;

public class QuestionJInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame implements InternalFrameListener  {
private  MainSplitPane mainSplitPanel=null;
private String mFileName;
private MainJPanel mainPanel=null;


//public PDFInternalFrame(File file, int mainFormWidth){
public QuestionJInternalFrame(File file, int mainFormWidth, int height){

    super(file.getName(), true, true, true, true);  
    //so that you can decide whether to close it or not
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    addInternalFrameListener(this);
    mFileName=file.getName();   

   /* mainSplitPanel=new MainSplitPane(file,mainFormWidth);
    this.add(mainSplitPanel.getMainPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    mainPanel=new MainJPanel(file,mainFormWidth, height);
    this.add(mainPanel.getMainPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);*/
    JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
    lbl.setText(mFileName);
    lbl.setVisible(true);
    this.add(lbl);

}

public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
      //closing();

    }

    public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e) {


    }

    public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }

    public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }

    public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }

    public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }

    public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {

    }



}
```

There is two pdf files opening at Adobe Reader on Windows:
[image]

By clicking the Tile --> Vertically on Window menu in Adobe Reader. The two Adobe Reader windows tile vertically as the image bellows.
[image]

Comment: You're describing [internal frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc The JFrame has JInternal Frame.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I want my project as like Adobe Reader. The Adobe Reader open each pdf on difference window and has function to cascade or tile all windows for PDF file on menu bar.